# How to change date format in multidimensional array and iterate all array with key

Tags: php, laravel

I have a multidimensional array with key and value and some key is empty also. Then I want to set a value for internal not empty array.

```
 $oldArray = array("Lexus LS600" => array(), 
                   "Toyota Alphard" => array(), 
                   "Benz S550" => array(0 => array(
                        "card_no" => "G2FPCBS3",
                        "travel_date" => "2020-09-10"
                        "travel_time" => "16:15:00",
                        "car_id" => 12,
                        "return_time" => "17:25")),
                   "BMW X6" => array());
```

I had this array but I want to set `return_time` `00:00` all over array. I tried foreach loop but foreach is remove empty array but I want empty array also.

I want this type array:-

```
$newArray = array("Lexus LS600" => array(), 
                  "Toyota Alphard" => array(), 
                  "Benz S550" => array(0 => array(
                       "card_no" => "G2FPCBS3",
                       "travel_date" => "2020-09-10"
                       "travel_time" => "16:15:00",
                       "car_id" => 12,
                       "return_time" => "00:00")),
                  "BMW X6" => array());
```

Comment: where your code which you have tried put those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this foreach again, I think it will solve your problem if I understood you correctly.

```
foreach ($arrays as $key => $values) {
    if (is_array($values)) {
        if (count($values)) {
            foreach ($values as $index => $data) {
                $arrays[$key][$index]['return_time'] = "00:00";
            }
        } else {
            $arrays[$key] = $values;
        }
    }
}
```

It will change **return_time** to "00:00" and also retain the empty index to your array.

Answer (score 1):

[array_walk_recursive()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-walk-recursive.php) is very suitable for this.

```
$oldArray = array("Lexus LS600" => array(), 
                   "Toyota Alphard" => array(), 
                   "Benz S550" => array(0 => array(
                        "card_no" => "G2FPCBS3",
                        "travel_date" => "2020-09-10",
                        "travel_time" => "16:15:00",
                        "car_id" => 12,
                        "return_time" => "17:25")),
                   "BMW X6" => array());

$keySearch = "return_time";
$replaceWith = "00:00";

array_walk_recursive(
  $oldArray,
  function(&$val,$key) use($keySearch,$replaceWith){
    if($key == $keySearch) $val = $replaceWith; 
  }
);

var_export($oldArray);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Lexus LS600' => 
  array (
  ),
  'Toyota Alphard' => 
  array (
  ),
  'Benz S550' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'card_no' => 'G2FPCBS3',
      'travel_date' => '2020-09-10',
      'travel_time' => '16:15:00',
      'car_id' => 12,
      'return_time' => '00:00',
    ),
  ),
  'BMW X6' => 
  array (
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two foreach loops to traverse the limited-depth array and make all values modifiable by reference (`&` before the variable).  In doing so, you don't need to create a separate array, just update the input array.  **It is SUPER easy to read and maintain.**

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/egEf9))

```
foreach ($array as &$cars) {
    foreach ($cars as &$entry) {
        if ($entry) {
            $entry["return_time"] = "00:00";
        }
    }
}
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Lexus LS600' => 
  array (
  ),
  'Toyota Alphard' => 
  array (
  ),
  'Benz S550' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'card_no' => 'G2FPCBS3',
      'travel_date' => '2020-09-10',
      'travel_time' => '16:15:00',
      'car_id' => 12,
      'return_time' => '00:00',
    ),
  ),
  'BMW X6' => 
  array (
  ),
)
```